# How can I fetch User ID as document on firebase in my data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch a name inside a document. The document ID is now the User UID. I want to fetch the UID but seems like I'm not getting something right with my queries. What I'm actually doing is trying to pass a value inside the .doc, which seems to not work.

I have tried db.collection('users').doc(userUid), I've tried .where(UserUid). Been trying to debug it with console, but I'm just getting the document ref object, as if nothing is wrong.

I think there is nothing wrong because the code will list the field I want in all collections if I just run it as ".collection('users')" without the .doc extension, I just think I am having a hard time understanding how to fetch the userUid as a value from the documents inside the collection "users" with my queries.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

```
    created () {

      var auth = firebase.auth()
      var userUid = auth.currentUser.uid
      var db = firebase.firestore()
      const collection = db.collection('users')/*

                                         | This works without the
                                         | .doc extension */.doc(userUid)

      collection.onSnapshot(res => {
        const changes = res.docChanges()
          changes.forEach(change => {
            if (change.type === 'added') {
              this.items.push({
                ...change.doc.data(),
                id: change.doc.id
              })
            }
          })
        })
      },
```

Comment: I'm unclear.  What's your final goal here? To get a single field of all the documents in a collection?  To get a field of a single document?  Do you need live updates using onSnapshot as you're showing, or do you need to fetch just a single time?  I'm also not sure what you mean by "I'm just getting the document ref object as if nothing is wrong".

Comment: Are you looking for `const userDoc = await db.collection('users').doc(userUid).get();` ?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a little bit, i figured out a solution on how to fetch:
collection >
  user UID > 
    (random field inside document)

such as this:

```
<template>

  <h1>

    {{ items.nameOfUser }}

  </h1>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: null
  }),
  async created () {
    const firestore = firebase.firestore()
    const docPath = firestore.doc('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    docPath.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc && doc.exists) {
        this.nameOfUser = doc.data()
      }
    })
  },
}
```